# What to name my config classes

Tags: java, coding-style, class, configuration

What name should I give classes which are just for configuration? For example, when using JAX-RS, every application is required to have an `Application` class which extends the superclass `javax.ws.rs.Application` like so. The Application class is just to register the list of resource classes.

```
public class APPLICATION_NAME_HERE extends Application {
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return new HashSet<Class<?>>(){{
            add(RestfulResource.class);
            add(AnotherRestfulResource.class);
        }};
    }
}
```

All the tutorials I see call the class MyApplication or TestApplication or something like that. But none of these sound professional. I can't call the class Application either because it is extending Application, and Java shadows the imported Application with my class. What is the common convention for naming classes like this?

Comment: What do you call the executable?

Comment: @DanPichelman depends on the project, for ex. `API` for this particular case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make up a name for your application, and use that. It doesn't have to mean anything, so you can make up a nonsense word, or just pick the name of something irrelevant that you'd like to refer to.

As well as giving you something to name this sort of class, this name should help you talk about your application unambiguously with your colleagues.

It seems currently you are calling your application API. I would look for something less general. What happens if your team needs to start maintaining two different API projects?

Comment: So just like `StorefrontAPIApplication`?

Comment: No, I was thinking more like make up a word that doesn't mean anything relavent like 'dizex' or whatever. If you start using that you'll learn soon enough that it's the name of your particular application.

Comment: You might want to wait a few hours or days for other answers before choosing an answer to accept.